# how to find PATH for pipenv install

Tags: path, pip, pipenv

I was installing pipenv from pip 19.3.1 for a python 3.7 project on windows

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

I got the expected error of Pipenv not in PATH. 
However before I was able to copy the appropriate line of code to add to as a PATH variable I closed command prompt accidentally and now I cannot find the variable which I need to add to PATH for Pipenv to function.

How can I find this line?

Answer (score 0):

On Unix/Linux `pip install --user` installs packages into `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y` and scripts into  `~/.local/bin`.

Windows: `%APPDATA%Python` (`lib` and `Scripts`)

See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-user